# firefox (v22) problems with css columns

Tags: css, firefox

Implementing css columns: just columned content with wrapper div:

http://jsfiddle.net/AmqD5/4/

It all works in webkit and older (prior firefox 22) versions. And in v22 content behaves strangely (there are no columns and it depends on the window size).

Is it a bug of new version or there is may be a workaround (some other css rules) to make content work as in webkit and older versions?

HMTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="columns">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    position: absolute;    
    left: 100px;
    outline: 1px dashed red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 407px;
}

.columns {
position: absolute; 
    left: 0px; 
    right: 0px; 
    -webkit-column-width: 276px; 
    -webkit-column-gap: 25px; 
    -webkit-column-rule: 0px none; 
    -moz-column-width: 276px; 
    -moz-column-gap: 25px; 
    -moz-column-rule: 0px none; 
    height: 407px; 
    font-size: 20px; text-align: left; 
    -moz-user-select: none; 
    cursor: default; 
    visibility: visible; 
    display: block;    
}
```

Comment: I don't see the problem in your fiddle.  FF22 looks about the same a Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try  `position: relative;`. Problem aparently solved

```
.columns {
   position: relative; 
   ...
}
```

Demo Here: http://jsfiddle.net/p3VHh/

Comment: Well I too found it. But it turned to be not a solution for me, as layout in my actual application is much more complex then in fiddle example. It seems that ff has some real strange bug in that version that I can not figure out. The result even depends on the style of internal paragraphs...

Comment: Btw, do you have any suggestions why it can work different ways with absolute and relative positioning?